# Duplicates of squares going in the wrong direction pygame

Tags: python, pygame

The program is supposed to make 3 squares and move them to the right. That works well. However, there are 2 squares that move down even though there are no functions to do that. there are only 3 square creating functions but there are 2 more that appear

```
import pygame

import random
import time
enemyCoordList = []
pygame.init()
rand = random.Random()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))

px = 30

py = 30


def enemy(x, y, sizex=30, sizey=30, health=0, speed=6,):
    # pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), pygame.Rect(x, y, sizex, sizey))
    enemyCoordList.append(x)
    enemyCoordList.append(y)


def drawEnemy():
    for l in range(len(enemyCoordList)-1):
        # print(range(len(enemyCoordList)))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), pygame.Rect(enemyCoordList[l], enemyCoordList[l+1], 50, 50))


enemy(30, 30)

enemy(50, 50)

enemy(100,100)
print(enemyCoordList)
run = True
while run:


    time.sleep(0.05)
    screen.fill((9, 68, 43))

    drawEnemy()
    for i in range(len(enemyCoordList)):
        #print(i)
        if i % 2 != 0:
            #print(i)
            continue
        # print(enemyCoordList)
        #print(i)
        enemyCoordList[i] += 1

    # for i in enemyCoordList:

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: a suggestion: the code would be easier to reason about if `enemyCoordList` was a list of `(x, y)` coordinate tuples, like `[(0,0), (30,30), ...]` instead of a flat list like `[0, 0, 30, 30]`. That would allow you to have loops like `for x, y in enemyCoordList`

Answer (score 0):

A coordinate has 2 components so:

<s>`for l in range(len(enemyCoordList)-1):`</s>

```py
for l in range(0, len(enemyCoordList), 2):
```

Correct `drawEnemy` function:

```
def drawEnemy():
    for l in range(0, len(enemyCoordList), 2):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), pygame.Rect(enemyCoordList[l], enemyCoordList[l+1], 50, 50))
```

---

However, it would be much easier to work with a list of coordinate pairs (list of lists):

```py
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()
rand = random.Random()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))

def enemy(x, y, sizex=30, sizey=30, health=0, speed=6):
    enemyCoordList.append([x, y])

def drawEnemy():
    for x, y in enemyCoordList:
         pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), pygame.Rect(x, y, 50, 50))

enemyCoordList = []
enemy(30, 30)
enemy(50, 50)
enemy(100,100)
print(enemyCoordList)

run = True
while run:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    for pos in enemyCoordList:
        pos[0] += 1

    screen.fill((9, 68, 43))
    drawEnemy()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```